# How to use Microsoft Graph to create a user in B2C with MFA authentication

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I know that I can use B2C policy flow UI to create a user with MFA authentication.

My project requires users be created using the application UI, not B2C policy flow UI.

How can I use Microsoft Graph to create a user with 2 factor authentication (cellphone + password) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to create a user with password as below using the tenant Id of azure ad b2c application.

Create an app registeration with all the required Application and delegated  permissions like `User.ReadWrite.All , User.AuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All , Directory.ReadWrite.All,Contacts.ReadWrite`
First get the access token of the App with all the required permissions :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token
?client_id=”
&client_secret=
&grant_type=
&redirect_uri=
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

Use the access token to create users with authenticationmethods:

**POST** **`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`**

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Axxx",
  "mailNickname": "AdxxV",
  "userPrincipalName": "adxxxe@xl.onmicrosoftxxx.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "xWwvxxx+bWH-d"
  }
}
```

> To add a new phone authentication , follow as below  Adding a phone
> number makes it available for use in both Azure multi-factor
> authentication (MFA)

**POST** **`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<UserUPN>/authentication/phoneMethods`**

Authorization : Bearer {Token}
Content-type : application/json

Body:
{
"phoneNumber": "+1 2065555555",
"phoneType": "mobile"
}

**Output:**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(xxfdd861')/authentication/phoneMethods/$entity",
    "id": "3179e48axxxxx",
    "phoneNumber": "+1 2065555555",
    "phoneType": "mobile",
    "smsSignInState": "notAllowedByPolicy"
}
```

[image]

See: [Create phoneMethod - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-post-phonemethods?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

For password might be created as shown in the beginning .
Else check for the passwords and then reset it .
Check for passwords:
**GET** `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userPrincipalName}/authentication/passwordMethods/28c10230-6103-485e-b985-444c60001490`

[image]

Then do a password by resetting it:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<upn>/authentication/passwordMethods/28c10230-6103-485e-b985-444c60001490/resetPassword
```

[image]

See :[authenticationMethod: resetPassword - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethod-resetpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[image]

GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/objectID/authentication/methods`

This is the method i used and AFIK There is no direct method for 2factor auth but alternatively you can enable MFA using [conditional access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conditionalaccessroot-post-policies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) .

**Reference :** [Manage resources with Microsoft Graph - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations)